# Why '\n' is not working with ServiceNow script? New lines not being created

Tags: javascript, servicenow

We have tried several variations of `'\n'` and tried `'\r'` but the script keeps returning the lines together or with spaces in between, not as actual new lines. Here is the script with the issue on the bottom two:

```
(function(current, previous, gs, action) {
    var eqStr ='cmdb_ci=' + current.getValue('cmdb_ci');

//eqStr='short_description=' + current.getValue('short_description');
    //eqStr += '^description=' + current.getValue('description');

    eqStr +='^priority=' + current.getValue('priority');
    eqStr +='^sys_domain=' + current.getValue('sys_domain');
    eqStr +='^company=' + current.getValue('company');
    eqStr +='^justification=' + current.getValue('number')
        + '\n' + current.getValue('short_description')
        + '\n' + current.getValue('description') ;
```

Comment: Its' `\n` and `\r` not `/n` and `/r` And, ultimately where will the string be output to? If it's being injected into a DOM element, you would get the results you are because `\n` is not the way to cause a line feed in HTML, `<br>` is. Those codes are only understood by the JS runtime.

Comment: @StephenP You should not edit/alter the content of a post like you did. You are assuming that the forward slashes were typos, when they might not have been. If you correct them in the question, you might have just fixed the problem without knowing it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the slashes in the title and text of the post were `/n` -- but the slashes in the *code* were the correct backslashes. I agree with you in general, but in this case it seemed clear it was the typing of the question that was in error, not the code.

Comment: How is this `eqStr` string used afterwards? In a `<div>` / `<p>`, input element `<textarea>`?

Comment: I accidentally put /n in the title but the code was correct with \n. So how would I use <br> in this case?

Comment: If the string is going to wind up as part of a DOM element, yes use `<br>`. The HTML parser doesn't know what JavaScript escape codes mean.

Comment: @StephenP In my experience, nothing is clear until the OP has stated it. I guessed the same thing you did, but that's why we have comments. Point it out to the OP and let them let us know instead of us perhaps guessing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If the string you are building is going to wind up being injected into a DOM element, you have to use codes that the HTML parser, which is responsible for parsing DOM elements, is familiar with. The HTML parser has no knowledge of JavaScript string escape codes as shown here:

```js
let output = "This is\na test.";
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = output;

let output2 = "This is\nanother test.";
document.querySelector("p").textContent = output2;
```

```html
<div></div>
<p></p>
```

For strings that will become part of a DOM element, you need to use the HTML tags that create line breaks, `<br>`:

```js
let output = "This is<br>a test.";
// innerHTML invokes the parser to parse the supplied string:
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = output;

let output2 = "This is<br>another test.";
// This won't produce the line break because textContent doesn't invoke the HTML
// parser. Insted, the actual text will be placed in the string.
document.querySelector("p").textContent = output2;
```

```html
<div></div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Hi Scott, we ended up using this for the bottom two lines- eqStr +='^justification=' + current.getValue('number') + "%0d%0a" + current.getValue('short_description') + "%0d%0a"+ current.getValue('description') ;